# Azure SQL Server VM with personal SQL Server production key

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-virtual-machine

I created an Azure SQL Server Standard VM. As the price page showing, VM with SQL Server installed will charge additional SQL Server fee.

Now I found I have a SQL Server Enterprise key. After I upgrade my pre-installed SQL Server Standard version to Enterprise version, will I still be charged the SQL Server fee?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> After I upgrade my pre-installed Standard version Sql server to
>   Enterprise version. Will I still be charged the Sql Server fee?

**Yes.**

If you want to use your own key, you have to strat from a regular Windows Server VM (and not SQL Server VM). Then, on top of that Windows Server, you install your version of SQL Server with your key.

Comment: Thanks , astaykov! I understand that I can start over from a new empty VM. However, my current running Sql Server VM include lots of configuration and database settings, if I start over with a new installation. Lots of work needs be done. and there may be some downtime, and I have to also migrate database to new server too. I have now successfully upgrade Sql Server Standard to Enterprise. I am wondering if there is a way that Azure will no longer charge me the Sql Server part since I am using my own Key.

Comment: No. There is no such way that I m aware of, when you based your work on SQL Server VM. But at least you are charged only for Standard edition instead of Enterprise :)

Comment: Now you can use the AHUB benefit on Azure SQL VMs from the SQL Server Management page.